# Splash screen not showing on hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm building a Hololens app in Unity.
Lately the splashscreen is only showing for a split second and is also frozen, if i move my head it has graphical glitches, the same you see when your hololens is experiencing heavy load in the background.

How can i determine the cause of this problem?
I tried looking at my awake functions, since i read they are run in the background while the splash screen is shown. They don't seem to be the issue though.

Any thoughts on things i could look into?

Comment: The first step into into solving this is to create a new empty project then run it to see if the splash screen is showing or not.

Comment: I did that already. It does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by going back through the commits.
It stopped working when i assigned mesh colliders to a big object in the scene. I guess the scene is loaded in the background while the splashscreen is shown and mesh colliders are even less performant than i thought.